# Element not found in dynamic pages

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

When working with dynamic pages in selenium, I want to pass the test without skipping the condition(like if element not found case). How to find the element?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? What is approach you have taken? Do you want to simply pass the test or find the element?

Comment: use wait until element not found.

Comment: You specify the `selenium2` tag, yet you specify `selenium-ide`.  Read the wiki of `selenium` to figure out the difference and disambiguate those terms for accurate answers please.

Answer (score 0):

Use Explicit wait until element not found,

```
WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element)
```

more info [click here](http://www.bizalgo.com/2012/01/14/timing-races-selenium-2-implicit-waits-explicit-waits/), Hope it will works for you.